# How to login to the SQLServer with Windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2012, virtualbox

Actually I have `Mac OS X` on to which I have installed `VirtualBox`, which has `Windows 7` installed. 
In that `Windows 7` I installed `SQLServer 2012`.

I can't log in to `SQLServer`. Could this setup prevent me from authenticating with `SQLServer`?

Answer (score 2):

To enable Windows Authentication on SQL Server

Start SQL Server Management Studio and in the Connect to Server dialog box, specify a SQL Server name and administrator credentials to connect to the server.

In Object Explorer, expand the SQL Server.

Expand Security, right-click Logins, and then click New Login.

In the Login – New window, for the Login name text box, specify the Windows user name in the format domain\username.

In the left pane, click User Mapping. In the right pane, select a database to associate with the user. In the Database role membership for box, select the db_owner check box.

Click OK.